# IOS6 Developed application suppport in ios7?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode4.5, ios6.0

Hello I am  Develop the  ios6 supporting application.My thought is ios 6 developed application  is compitaple on ios7 or any otherway is available? and also If I developing the application using ios 7 is supporting earlier versions.Give the best solution for me.

Comment: Did you read the transition guide that Apple posted on the front page of the iOS Developer Center?

Comment: @StephenDarlington Yes..I read I need more clarification

Answer (score 3):

An app compiled for iOS 6 runs in a special compatibility mode on iOS 7.

When you compile with Xcode 5 you must support at least iOS 7. By setting the "Deployment Target" you can also support older versions, but if you use features that are only available in iOS 7 you need to check first otherwise your app will crash on iOS 6.

Also note that the various UI components on iOS 7 are different sizes than on iOS 6. You need to cater for that either using Interface Builder (autolayout possibly) or in your code. How to do this is detailed in the [iOS 7 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/WWDR/iOSUITransitionGuide).

The *easiest* solution is to only support iOS 7. The *best* option depends entirely on your circumstances, customer base, etc.